# Connect to PostgreSQL using integrated security or fall back to public login

Tags: postgresql, windows-authentication, npgsql, sspi, integrated-security

I am using Npgsql and I was wondering whether there was a way to connect to a PostgreSQL server using integrated security that automatically falls back to a public login? Or maybe there is another way to do what I am trying to achieve.

I have an ASP.NET web site (IIS7.5) that uses Windows Authentication, and I have configured PostgreSQL to allow access via SSPI, this works fine as long as there is a role with the right name in the database. The web site is available for everyone on the intranet to view but some users have a few extra abilities (or can see extra data) that everyone else should not be able to do.

Currently, I am using something like the following:

```
NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder csb = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder();

csb.Pooling = false; // if true, causes intermittent DB connection issues
csb.Database = "dbname";
csb.Host = "192.168.1.100";
csb.IntegratedSecurity = true;

dbconn.ConnectionString = csb.ConnectionString;

try
{
    dbconn.Connect();
}
catch (NpgsqlException ex)
{
    if (/* check for authentication failed */)
    {
        csb.IntegratedSecurity = false;
        csb.UserName = "www-read";
        dbconn.ConnectionString = csb.ConnectionString;
        dbconn.Open();
    }
}
```

This works fine, except for each time it falls back to the "www-read" role, it adds a critical log entry saying that there was an authentication error. The only way I can see around this is always connecting via www-read and querying whether a suitable integrated-security role exists and reconnecting, but that seems even more cumbersome than the above.

Answer (score 1):

Integrated Security for Postgres on Windows can be done with some caveats by editing 2 files in your postgresql data directory.

1. `pg_ident.conf` maps A/D logins to postgres usernames:

```
# MAPNAME   A/D LOGIN                 PG-USERNAME
#
MapForSSPI  Login@DOMAINNAME          www-read
MapForSSPI  OtherLogin@DOMAINNAME     or-whatever-pg-rolename
```

I'm not sure there is a better option here than individually listing all users (or service accounts?) who you will permit to use integrated login. Every A/D login has to be mapped to a Postgres username. So this is probably only viable for a short and closely-controlled list.

2. `pg_hba.conf` then permits the PG-USERNAMEs you listed above to use integrated security as a login method. Put these user-specific lines above any user `all` lines. (Often in pg_hba.conf you rely on user `all` lines to permit anyone to login with their username & password).

```
#== put these lines above any catchall lines ==
# TYPE  DATABASE  USER      ADDRESS       METHOD
host    all       www-read  <yourIP4net>  sspi  map=MapForSSPI
host    all       www-read  <yourIP6net>  sspi  map=MapForSSPI
```

The caveat is that this only works on a machine in a Windows Domain (presumably your normal situation at work) or else only on localhost.

More details: https://www.cafe-encounter.net/p2034/postgres-using-integrated-security-on-windows-on-localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any passwords in your code. Are you using any security at all?

If you don't want to embed password into your source code (and rightly so), you should create `~/.pgpass` file in your home directory (`%appdata%/postgresql/pgpass.conf` on Windows) which has 1 or more lines like this:

```
hostname:port:database:username:password
```

This will allow any program that is using libpq (including npgsql) to look up for passwords from .pgpass upon any connection attempt.

If this will run under www-data user, .pgpass should be created in its home directory (but be sure to configure your web server not to serve this file ever!)

I think doing this should also fix problem with connection pooling that you seem to have.

Comment: I don't use a password for integrated security because it is handled automatically (that is the whole purpose of integrated security). I omitted the password in the code above because it isn't relevant, the above was only to demonstrate more-or-less what I am doing. Anyway the problem is not with logging in, the problem is that I want to automatically fall back to non-integrated-security *without* having to catch exceptions or cause PostgreSQL to log it as a fatal error.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misinterpreted your question then. But, hey, my recipe should work if you want practical solution! :-)

Comment: Is this critical log about authentication a big concern to you? Npgsql only connects using a single authentication method each time. It doesn't have any option to automatically try other authentication types when another one fails. I think the best way to handle your problem is doing like you did: try first windows authentication and if it fails, try the username-password.

Comment: The only problem with the .pgpass approach is that Npgsql isn't based on libpq. Npgsql has its own implementation of the Postgresql protocol on top of TCP, so this configuration won't be used by Npgsql based programs.